# Do the three races of starcraft 2 HOTS model rock paper scissors?

Tags: starcraft-2

Each race has distinct differences with infantry and air.  Is there such a model that makes one race superior over another? An example would be Terran is better than Zerg which is better than Protoss which beats Terran again.

If you grew up playing Pokemon, this is similar to the type of Pokemon you start out with, fire, water, grass.  To apply it to Starcraft 2, we may consider a firebat to be "fire", a zergling to be "grass" and a zealot to be "water".  Firebats might win against zerglings, zerglings would be able to swarm zealots, and zealots would just out damage the firebat...

In your experience of the game, have you seen this to exist?

Comment: No.  It's all skill based.

Comment: This is pure discussion, not a good fit for the site.

Comment: I disagree that this is pure discussion. I believe it is a fair question to ask if the races are intended to be evenly matched, or if there is a built in advantage/disadvantage to certain matchups. Certainly many who play will have this question - and I believe it is answerable with a wealth of balancing details provided by Blizz.

Comment: @EBongo Looking at Starcraft as a Rock Paper Scissors type of model will automatically introduce logical fallacies when choosing your opposing race.  And then we get questions like, "WTF!  Zerg beats Terran!  Why didn't I win?".  Maybe slightly related, something like [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1386/how-do-i-remember-which-units-counter-which-in-starcraft-2) is much better.

Comment: @fbueckert is your comment base on some research or is it your gut feeling? Can you provide some sources that back this up?

Comment: Lots and lots and lots of playing the original.  The reason there's such a huge competitive scene for Starcraft is *because* it's so balanced.  It's all about the player's skill, and not because any race has an advantage over another.

Comment: @fbueckert I think you are saying "SC HOTS is not a Rock Paper Scissors model" - which I see as a perfectly valid answer to the question - in fact the right one, which Hugo has provided and I upvoted.  To be clear, are you arguing for or against closure?

Comment: I'm arguing against the inherently discussion based question.  It's completely non-constructive because it introduces a false model as part of the question.  The only way TO answer that is, "No".  And questions where all you can answer is No, is a bad question. @EBongo

Comment: The original StarCraft expansion was like this to an extent, but that extent is extremely limited, on the order of 52% or 53% at most.

Comment: In any case, it's far too early to tell.

Comment: The answer is no.

Comment: I feel like the question is a concealed attempted to ask: "Is Starcraft 2 imbalanced?"

Answer (score 6):

For the moment, the "OP" units (though not game breaking) seem to be the Hellbats and the Tempest. I really feel that it's because they are new and people haven't found a good way to fight them yet (for the same reason voidray collossus was "OP" until zerg found out about fungal growth).

Starcraft 2 is made to be a competitive game, so all races have to be able to play against all races. Blizzard wants most unit in each race arsenal to have a role in most matchups. That is why the changed the reapers in HoTS, that is why the hydras got buffed and that is why the voidrays got changed too.

tldr; no, nothing is game breaking otherwise sc2 would be boring. Blizzard said the mathchups win/loss were pretty close in pro matches in a statement last week about game balance. They know about skytoss but they want to wait before doing any changes.

EDIT: I saw in the comments of the question that sources were asked, so i started doing some ressearch to help with my claims.

**Charts of the win/loss:**
http://www.sc2charts.net/en/edb

**Intwerview with Dustin Browder by Frodan:** http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=382616

**race distribution:**http://www.sc2ranks.com/stats/league/all/1/all/0/0/0

**IAMA with blizz dev team:** http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/blog/8983614/Reddit_AMA_Full_Transcript-3_6_2013

**balance report just before HoTS release:** http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/blog/8896362/Situation_Report_Heart_of_the_Swarm_Balance-3_4_2013

These are the stats I could find for now.

The race distribution is in WoL because Sc2 ranks have not updated their database with enough HoTS players for it to be reliable for now. Like it has been said in the comments, the balance of the races is a lot about skills (which is why it is so hard to do a perfect balance).

When you lose a game, check the replay, how many workers did you have, what were your upgrades, what was the angle of attack, did your opponent hide expos or tech, etc.

Answer (score 3):

No. Races aren't build with rock, paper, scissors model but their units have this "model".

If you see at this [Zealot wiki page](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Zealot) he is **Strong Against**; Marauder, Immortal, Zergling
and **Weak Against**; Hellion, Colossus, Roach.

To win games you need know how to build your race to make your army strong against enemy.